# TinyMCE - Inserting content at cursor position in IE doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

I'm trying to insert some content at the current cursor position or replace the selected content in a TinyMCE editor instance. I'm using this:

`tinyMCEPopup.editor.selection.setContent(content);`

Where `content` is a string of HTML that I want to insert.

It works great on Firefox, Opera and Chrome, but won't work in IE. Instead it inserts content at the beginning of the editor, instead of the selection. I've also tried:

`tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);`

Again, same behavior in IE. The TinyMCE code for inserting special characters uses the function above and that works! I've tried replicating it in my plugin and still no joy...

```
function insertChar(chr) {
    tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&#' + chr + ';');

    // Refocus in window
    if (tinyMCEPopup.isWindow)
        window.focus();

    tinyMCEPopup.editor.focus();
    tinyMCEPopup.close();
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Still not working in IE, Opera doesn't even show my plugin's button in the toolbar (although that's probably a separate issue)! I've now also tried the jQuery plugin, got the editors to load, but couldn't call the mceInsertContent method on it, even using this:

`$('#my-editor-id').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);`

Got an error: "object has no method: tinymce" - maybe I can't call that from a popup?!

Comment: Same situation for me. Using IE>=8 doesn't work! I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918773/textarea-tinymce-and-insert-an-image-in-textarea). The guy solved it (probably using the jQuery plugin). Using the JS code I confirm it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks David. Spent ages looking at this, nearly giving up on it. Just updated my question with my experience with the jQuery plugin. I'm pretty sure either IE or TinyMCE is junk, just no sure which yet :) I'm leaning towards IE though!

Comment: @greg84 **maybe I can't call that from a popup?!** Tinymce emotions plugin(emotions.js) uses the same  tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, file); for inserting icons at the cursor position and that works fine across all browsers including IE ...

Answer (score 4):

have you tried calling:

```
tinyMCEPopup.restoreSelection();
```

before calling

```
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&#' + chr + ';');
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that TinyMCE loses the current cursor position when you click on something else like a button or link outside the editor, that causes it to lose focus.
To solve the problem, use the mousedown event of the button or link. In that way you can perform the insert action before the focus is lost.

```
$("#insert_link").mousedown(function (e) {
    var editor = tinyMCE.get("editor");
    editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "Insert Value");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I had the above problem in TinyMCE v4.2.6 using jQuery mode but only when I configured an inline text editor. If I would set inline=false, the text would get inserted at the caret position as expected. However, using this solution, the text insert works correctly with inline mode on and off.

Answer (score 2):

What has worked for me in a similar scenario, and what might be a solution here - use

```
editor.selection.getBookmark();
```

before loosing focus of the editor
and

```
editor.selection.moveToBookmark();
```

before inserting the content.

The issue is that while in FF when you place the cursor at some spot in a text field containing text, then click elsewhere and return back (ie by hitting Tab) the caret will be displayed in the place where it was before focus was lost. In IE it will return to the beginning. I hope this helps.

Comment: Works great on later versions of Tiny, where mce_popup no longer exists.  Thanks!

Comment: This fix worked for me.  I had to create a local variable in the custom plugin I'm working with to store a copy of the bookmark "bkmrk = editor.selection.getBookmark()" then I created a restore method to do "... return editor.selection.moveToBookmark(bkmrk)"  which is called from the code via "tinyMCE.activeEditor.plugins["fmgattachment"].restoreBookmark();"